# Wiki software like OneNote with some extra options on Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, offline, note-taking, wiki

I've been using Microsoft Windows and [Microsoft OneNote](https://www.onenote.com/), but now I'm migrating to Linux (Ubuntu). As a result, I'm looking for a [wiki software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_software) which can replace OneNote, with the following features:

- running on Linux
- free of charge
- formatting text
- keeping multiple notes
- hierarchical structure
- links between notes
- notes can have images and hyperlinks
- online and offline backup for all notes
- syncing between machines
- distributed, offline editing
- sharing
- show some notice or warning when a note/image is deleted and there is a link to that
- show dead links
- work when no Internet connection

OneNote is a good application but it has some disadvantages. For example, a notebook could not be stored offline and online also it may contain dead links. It is also not free and it only works on Windows, although it is available on the web - I'm looking for both offline and online editing. What could be a good replacement given those requirements?

It is not necessary to be available "from outside" (e.g. a web service), and a local app suffice. No specific wiki format is preferred. Also, I prefer an open source software (for more security).

Comment: It seems to be better if complete content be available for read and write.

Comment: Write will be a bit tricky remotely if it's a local solution ;) But yes, sharing the complete article it is then.

Comment: umm tagspace is great but is bascially ment for tagging, You can also create md notes with it

Comment: Pavel seems to suggest a web-only solution. Are web-only solutions OK? Or should it work normally on Linux even when no Internet connection is available?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul It must work when there is no Internet connection.

Comment: Instead of having the editor support sync, you could maybe use an offline editor, and use Syncthing to synchronize your notes